# React-native Expo build: "Illegal option: -jarfile" Error when trying to generate SHA1 certificate for Google API key android

Tags: android, react-native, sha1, google-authentication, expo

I am following the steps mentioned in the "building standalone apps" section of the Google authentication integration and I am stuck at the step to generate "SHA-1 certificate fingerprint" as per the link https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google.html#run-keytool--list--printcert--jarfile-growlerapk--grep-sha1--awk--print-2--where-growlerapk-is-the-name-of-the-apk-produced-in-step-1

I get an error:

> Illegal option: -jarfile

when I run the command:

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile growler.apk | grep SHA1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

I see the same command is used in building standalone Android app for Facebook authentication as well.

Link for GitHub issue https://github.com/expo/exp/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to update your `keytool` binary. See
https://forums.expo.io/t/generate-androidstandaloneappclientid-help/3422/7